# Incorrect ping result from Ruby program

Tags: ruby, ping

I use the following code snippet to ping a series of IPs and check if they are reachable or not:

```
class Ping
  def self.pingecho(host = string.new, timeout = 10, service = "echo")
    begin
      puts host
      while(timeout) do
        s = TCPSocket.new(host, service)
        s.close
      end
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
      return true
    rescue Timeout::Error, StandardError
      return false
    end
    return true
  end
end
```

It returns the correct status except for two IPs on my list, for which the code returns `false`. But when I try to ping them directly through command prompt using the ping command, I get a response without any issues. If this is an issue with the code, then I should get incorrect results for the other IPs as well. But I have this issue only with these two.

I tried to pass these IPs directly to the class as:

```
Ping::pingecho(10.xx.xx.xx)
```

but I still get the result as `false`.

Any suggestions on what needs to be checked/corrected?

Comment: `Ping::pingecho(10.xx.xx.xx)` is invalid, isn't it?

Comment: Note that using the [Echo Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol) (as done by your code) uses a completely different protocol than the `ping` command which uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), which is *not* based on TCP. Different results are thus likely.

Comment: Are you sure that there is an echo server running at the host? That would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: If you'll remove StandardError from rescue list, what exception you'll get on these two hosts?

Comment: Hi Holger - thanks, that makes sense. But I have this issue only for these 2 IPs. For the other 2000 odd IPs in the list, the results of ping match with the results from echo (my program)

Comment: Hi Jorg - thanks, even I suspect something at the IP end whereby it is not accepting connections or something similar. Unfortunately I have limited knowledge of networking; so not sure how to check whether the IPs are configured in such a way that they 'understand' echo.

Comment: Hi Ivan - Thanks, I tried removing the StandardError. The result still says 'FALSE' for both IPs.

Comment: Additionally, when I remove the StandardError as suggested by Ivan, I get the following error: "`initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."